# SQL Server : selecting TOP Records and updating results in another table

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

This is rather complicated to explain in a title.

I have two tables, one that populates web visits by a user, the other is the user table that has a field that stores the last login date.

I want to base the last login date on the latest user visit by each user (if they are registered in the user table.

This will be user in a stored procedure.

Note: I have abbreviated the tables to the relevant columns.

TABLE `[Login]`

```
   [User] [VARCHAR](15) NOT NULL,
   [LogOn_Date] [DATETIME] NOT NULL
```

AND

TABLE `[Users]`

```
   [User] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
   [Last_Login_Dt] [datetime] NULL
```

I am looking to select the latest date `[LogOn_Date]` from each user in the `Login` table, then update the `Users` table with the `[LogOn_Date]` value in the `[Last_Login_Dt]` column that matches users.

Note: not all users that log on are in the `Users` table, I track everyone via windows authentication regardless if they are a user or not, but only want to update each user that is present in the `users` table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you do not have a last login field on the users table.  Unless you are having some performance concerns, in which case I would suggest an indexed view.

The view would look like

```
Select
   U.User, Max(L.LogOnDate)
   From Users U
   Join Login L On L.User = U.User
```

If you really want to persist this data in the users table I would suggest that you use the above Sql statement as the basis for your work.  There are a number of ways to update the users table.  The best might be an update statement with a join.

http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/56823/delete-update-rows-using-inner-join-sql-server/

Comment: Users.User' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. I would prefer not to use that column in the user table, but the stored procedure after that disables user accounts if they have not been active for X days. We lost our entire DB team and .Net developers are stuck with doing everything.

Comment: @MichaelHartmann you just have to add `Group By U.User` to the end of the query, but I have to agree that based on your comment above, that you dont need to update the table to store information that only gets used for a proc that deactivates users.  The Update, then checking the Last_Login_Dt field would take longer than just getting the `MAX(LogOn_Date)` in your deactivation query.

Comment: Joe's view works, and it would be ideal to do as you suggest, however, I don't know how to combine the view with the SP that disables the users. All our SQL staff members were moved, leaving .NET developers on our own. @jamieD77

Comment: If you can edit your post to include the SP I could show you how to use the view.  I am guessing that you want to deactivate users who have a last login date older than X.

Answer (score 1):

Query:

```
UPDATE u
SET u.Last_Login_Dt = l.LogOn_Date
FROM Users u
JOIN (SELECT 
      [User],
      max(LogOn_Date) AS LogOn_Date
      FROM Login
      GROUP BY [User]) l ON u.[User]= l.[User]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE u
SET u.Last_Login_Dt = l.LogOn_Date
FROM Users u
JOIN (SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User, ORDER BY LogOn_Date DESC) AS rn
      FROM Login) l ON u.user = l.user and l.rn = 1
```

The derived table ranks the users logins by date. Join it back to the users but only pull rank 1 which is the most recent login and update the users table

Comment: Can you please expand on what this does and how it addresses the OP?

Comment: @RoYoMi the derived table ranks the users logins by date. Join it back to the users but only pull rank 1 which is the most recent login and update the users table.

Answer (score 0):

```
update [Users]
set [Last_Login_Dt] = a.Last_Login_Dt
from 
    (select [User], max([Login_date]) as Last_Login_Dt 
     from Login 
     group by [User]) a 
join [SampleDb].[dbo].[Users] b on a.[User] = b.[User]
```